# Unity launcher right click focus

Tags: unity, launcher, focus

When right clicking an icon in the Unity launcher, the menu comes up but i cant select anything. Its like Unity does not have focus at all.

I have to click somewhere on the desktop and then the right click menu works correctly. This happens on all my installations of 11.10, but only after login. This is a serious bug since it totally breaks Unity if you dont know how to get around the bug.

Anyone experienced this ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. It is a known bug and people are working on it; https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/819721. It seems to have been fixed, and you can expect to get an update after things have been properly tested. Unity 4.26 should not have this issue.

Comment: Great :-) thx for the info.